# output html from jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i'm creating a gallery which is loaded from a directory. first im creating a div tag for each album folder in the directory. then im using jquery ajax to get the folder name that was clicked and create div tags for each image in that folder. im sending the id of the folder to an external php page to grab the file paths for the images. im not sure how to output actual html. quite new to ajax/php coding so explanations are helpful.

jquery ajax:

```
var jq=$.noConflict();
        jq(document).ready(function(){
        jq(".album-select").click(function(event){
        var id=event.target.id;
        jq.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "image_loader.php",
        data: {phpid:id},
        success: function(data){

            jq('#mydiv').html("");
            jq('#mydiv').append(data);
        }           



    });
```

image_loader.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['phpid'])) {
$album_fill = $_POST['phpid'];
}
$dir = 'images';
$slash = '/';
$dir_image = "$dir$slash$album_fill";
    $dir_contents = scandir($dir_image);
    foreach($dir_contents as $file){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
        $dir_imagepath = "$dir_image$slash$file";
            echo '<div style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; top:1100px; left:500px;">';
            echo '<img src="',$dir_imagepath,'">';
            echo '</div>';
            }}?>
```

Comment: What happens in your current code? If nothing, whats the console look like, any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all change your `success` function as follows:

```
   success: function(data){
        $('#mydiv').html(data);
    }
```

secondly, make sure your `ajax` call is returning an `HTML` page.

Comment: i replaced append with html as well buddy

Comment: Either way, emptying the `html` then appending the new will do the same as `.html("")` + `.html(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Take this

```
jq('#mydiv').html("");
jq('#mydiv').append(data);
```

And make it this

```
jq('#mydiv').html(data);
```